# How to remove div background color outline from border when presenting SVGs

Tags: html, svg, border, background-color

### How to remove div background color outline from border when presenting SVGs

When I upload my svg into the text editor and wrap it around a div which has a background color I notice that there is a faint outline of the div background color even when the facebook icon has fully met the sides of the circular div border. I want to remove the outline of the div background-color so that it's pixel perfect. Does anyone know how this van be fixed?

So far I've tried using the view box to zoom in on the svg slightly to make the sides meet. I've also tried using the box shadow property although I didn't really understand how that property would work.

With color as it is, the problem is only noticeable when you zoom in. If you change the background color to a lighter yellow though or another light color, it becomes more noticeable.

Apologies if this is not an appropriate question. It's got me pretty stuck and I wanted to give this a go.

```css
#facebook-icon {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-color:blueviolet;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="facebook-icon">
    <svg id="fb-svg" width="200px" height="200px" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="facebook" class="svg-inline--fa fa-facebook fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="17 17 460 460"><path fill="currentColor" d="M504 256C504 119 393 8 256 8S8 119 8 256c0 123.78 90.69 226.38 209.25 245V327.69h-63V256h63v-54.64c0-62.15 37-96.48 93.67-96.48 27.14 0 55.52 4.84 55.52 4.84v61h-31.28c-30.8 0-40.41 19.12-40.41 38.73V256h68.78l-11 71.69h-57.78V501C413.31 482.38 504 379.78 504 256z"></path></svg>
</div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: I see a black circle and purple 'F'. What exactly needs to be remoed?

Answer (score 0):

Your css `border-style` is set to `solid`.  It's displaying a black border around your element, as it should be doing.

Setting `border-style` to `none` removed the border for me, and gave me this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGE9K.png

You weren't seeing the background peek out, you were seeing the border.

Comment: Thanks Storjak. If you zoom in you can see a really faint purple/blue next to the border. It's more noticeable with lighter colors. Anyway your answer is helpful. Just before I got your response I set my border-width to 0px and it seemed to remove the faint outline. I've upvoted you, all though I don't have any reputation points so it won't show.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to change the border-width property of the div in CSS and noticed that no matter how wide I made the black border the background-color continued to peak through. However when I made the border-width come to 0px it finally fixed the issue. Now no matter how light the background-color it isn't visible.

```css
#facebook-icon {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-color:yellow;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="facebook-icon">
    <svg id="fb-svg" width="200px" height="200px" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="facebook" class="svg-inline--fa fa-facebook fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="17 17 460 460"><path fill="currentColor" d="M504 256C504 119 393 8 256 8S8 119 8 256c0 123.78 90.69 226.38 209.25 245V327.69h-63V256h63v-54.64c0-62.15 37-96.48 93.67-96.48 27.14 0 55.52 4.84 55.52 4.84v61h-31.28c-30.8 0-40.41 19.12-40.41 38.73V256h68.78l-11 71.69h-57.78V501C413.31 482.38 504 379.78 504 256z"></path></svg>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```